# Newly created or modified java files not running in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, classnotfoundexception, java.lang.class

I have a folder named java where i keep all the .java files
Recently I created a new java file to solve a simple DSA problem named MinimumTime.java

```
public class MinimumTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MinimumTime ob1 = new MinimumTime();
        int a[][]={
            {1,1},
            {3,4},
            {-1,0}
        };
        System.out.println(ob1.minTimeToVisitAllPoints(a));
    }
    public int minTimeToVisitAllPoints(int[][] points) {
        int n=points.length;
        if(n==1){
            return 0;
        }
        int time=0;
        for (int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
            int xDiff = Math.abs(points[i][0] - points[i - 1][0]);
            int yDiff = Math.abs(points[i][1] - points[i - 1][1]);
            time += Math.max(xDiff, yDiff);
        }
        return time;
    }
}
```

This is the code but when i click the Run button on the top right corner i get this error in the terminal
`Error: Could not find or load main class MinimumTime Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MinimumTime`
I thought it was problem with the jdk so to check it i tried the
`javac MinimumTime.java`
and
`java MinimumTime`
both were working perfectly fine it was creating a new .class file and executing the code as expected so i tried running other java files in the same folder they were working as expected so i tried modifying the code in an existing file and it was not working anymore and was giving the same error

i tried running other java files in the same folder they were working as expected so i tried modifying the code in an existing file and it was not working anymore and was giving the same error

Edit: I just created an new .java file named
Test.java
in that i intentionally named the class with the main fucntion as
class MinimumTime
it was giving the error
`Error: Could not find or load main class MinimumTime Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MinimumTime`
in stead of
`Error: Could not find or load main class Test Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test`

Comment: There is no problem with the code here. What is your file name? Is it consistent with the class name? Also describe how you get error information in detail, step by step. Finally, if you click the `Run` above the editing page Main method to execute the script?

Comment: Yes the filename and the class name are same if i dont compile the code manually by clicking the run button it is not working and giving this error if i give the wrong name for class for example test.java has test2 as main class it is saying Error: Could not find or load main class test2 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test2 not for test if i modify an existing file it is showing error but before editing it is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code in the problem. Follow the following steps

1. New script, named `MinimumTime.java`

   [image]
2. Paste the code in the post
3. Click the RUN execution code above the main method

   [image]

If you have been wrong, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` and restart vscode.